# Getting my organisation's events

Tags: github-api

Through Github's API (and logged in with my user), I'm trying to get the events (or activity) of my organisation. I think I've got it right. So far I'm using this request URL:
`https://api.github.com/orgs/:org/events?key`

If I use "github" as :org, I get the stream alright, but if I use my organisation name it responds with an empty array. From what I understad it's because of the private settings of the organisation.

Now, how can I get my stream, using my authenticated user, without changing my organisation's privacy settings?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK found it: https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-events-for-an-organization

The proper request is at: `GET /users/:username/events/orgs/:org`

Who would have believed you need to go through a user, to get an organisation's events..?